# What is the suggested approach for creating 'widgets' in AngularJs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web, single-page-application

I want to create pages that are composed of widget style components, each fed dynamically from its own backend data source (SignalR).

I want to be able to develop these components separately, and test them independently, then compose pages by dropping them into a framework.

Using AngularJs, what is the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create each widget on it's own module and then on the main AngularJS app I would inject those modules as a dependency.

Something like this:

```
    // bundling a set of directives/widgets in a module. 
    // You can create a module for each widget though...
    (function(){
          var app = angular.module('myWidgets',[]);
          app.factory('serviceTwo',['$http',function($http){...my service code}]);
          app.directive('widgetOne',function(){...etc});
          app.directive('widgetTwo',['serviceTwo',function(serviceTwo){...}]);
    })();
```

Then on the «consumer» application...

```
    (function(){
        var myConsumerApp = angular.module('myConsumerApp',['myWidgets']);
        etc...
     })();
```

Then you can use the directives just you would do in any other way in your main app:

```
    <div ng-app="myConsumerApp">

       <widget-one></widget-one>
       <widget-two></widget-two> etc...

    </div>
```

This would be my approach.